# Generic term for Person or Corporation

Tags: single-word-requests, generic-term

In a financial sense, what would be a generic name for an entity that can be a single individual or a corporation that has an account such a bank or credit card account? I see the [IRS](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/classification-of-taxpayers-for-u-s-tax-purposes) calls it "person", was wondering if there would be a better word for it.

Comment: Owner?  As in account owner?

Comment: Yes, an account holder.

Comment: There are two types of person: a legal person (corporation) and an individual (person). According to a recent Supreme Court decision, corporations (unfortunately) have legal personhood. Nevertheless, companies have business bank accounts and individuals in it (board members or others) are authorized to sign on behalf of the company.

Comment: Please include a sentence where the word or phrase would be used. The following is the strict guideline of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A ***party***.

ODO:

> **[party](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/party)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **3** A person or people forming one side in an agreement or dispute.
>   ‘a contract between two parties’

businessdictionary.com:

> **[party](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/party.html)**
>   Entity that takes part or is involved in an agreement, lawsuit, or transaction.

Comment: So in this case, if I am an account holder with a bank, I am a party and the bank would be the other party?

Comment: @OtávioDécio, that's right.

Comment: You are only a party if there is a contract. You are the account holder and the bank is the bank.

Comment: I would never use the word in financial context to mean an account holder. As @Lambie commented, you are just an (corporate or personal) account holder.